# Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.MIMEException

Tags: c#, biztalk, mime, pop3

i have a problem with POP3 adapter in Biztalk. After setting up it in my receive location some mails throws the MIMEException that you can see in the title.

The e-mail contains only some attachments.

Comment: Can we have the rest of the exception message?  That may give us more details as to what the issue is.

Comment: A message received by adapter "POP3" on receive location "ReceivePop" with URI "POP3://###########" is suspended. 
 Error details: Exception of type 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.MIMEException' was thrown. 
 MessageId:  {CC524C02-8064-4BAB-97A2-B02F51EDEB2A}
 InstanceID: {DA33C96B-83D8-4DC8-9C4D-5BF534DFB20A}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post stating the same issue along with its solution. Hope the solution will work for you. ["Failed to decode the S/MIME message. The S/MIME message may not be valid." when using POP adapter to process incoming emails](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/apacbiztalk/archive/2013/11/01/quot-failed-to-decode-the-s-mime-message-the-s-mime-message-may-not-be-valid-quot-when-using-pop-adapter-to-process-incoming-emails-in-biztalk-server-2009.aspx)

Comment: What BizTalk version are you working on? Have you tried this hot fix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982634/en-us

Comment: Do not copy paste solution links. Links can be wrong over time.

Comment: im working on 2013 version, yes i installed it but same exception

Answer (score 0):

Get the email text, this should contain the attachment, email body and some properties. Validate this email message, there are lots of MIME validation web site available.

It will give you the result of the line number of your MIME message that failed. Usually some of the lines are too long which sometimes exceed more than `998` characters.

Sample long lines are those diagnostics from anti-spam software that are installed on mail servers.

You can add custom pipeline decoder component to format those long lines and add SMIME/MIME decoder component. Make sure to copy pop3 context properties in case you need them.

Here's some code snippet on how to break the MIME message

```
public IBaseMessage Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)
{
            System.IO.Stream st = pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(st);
            var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            string str = string.Empty;
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                str  = reader.ReadLine();
                if (str.Length >= 998)                            
                   str = str.Replace(str.ToString(), System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str.ToString(), "(.{" + 998 + "})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine));

                strBuilder.AppendLine(str);
            }             

            System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(m);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            writer.Write(strBuilder.ToString());
            m.Position = 0;
            pInMsg.BodyPart.Data = m;                
            reader.Close();
            return pInMsg;                    
}
```